# Can't boot up computer windows 8 installation

Tags: installation, windows-8-preview, windows-installation

I wanted to install Windows 8 with a volume partition and when the Windows 8 was installing it rebooted and it gave me an error:

> The digital signature for this file couldn't be verified. File :windows \system 32\winload.exe error code 0xc0000428.

I have tried bootec commands and they didn't seem to fix it.

Also my Windows 7 got deleted and I only have to boot with the Windows 8 error, so I can't do anything not even boot to safe mode.  I have tried to install Windows 8 from disk later on and it won't let me because it keeps rebooting and starting the installation again, so I took off the disk before it rebooted and it takes me to that error again.

Remember that's my only boot option so I'm stuck in the installation disk.

Comment: It sounds like the installation media you are using is corrupt. What Windows 8 release are you using exactly?  I suggest you wait until Windows 8 RTM can be purchased.  There isn't a point in using release preview.

Comment: I'm using consumer preview but I can't boot to any system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have data on the system? If not then there should be an option (from the boot DVD) to install a new copy of Windows 8 (starting again).

Failing that, use a livecd/BootCD (Hirens) to format or remove the partition (using something like GParted) to ease starting the Windows install again.

Comment: If u mean to choose a operating system then no I turned the computer and gives the screen of the error but I could enter the recovery through the installation dvd . I think its because of a volume partion problem

Comment: Thanks for the accept, any progress after removing the partition?